# Reverse array with using pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, reverse

```
#include <stdio .h>
#include <stdlib .h> 
int main(){
    char text1 [N] ; 
    char reverse [N] ;
    char* txtptr = text1 ;
    char* revtxtptr = reverse ;
    int N;
    printf (”\n Enter any text here : ”) ;
    scanf(”%s”, text1); 
    while(N> 0){
        txtptr --;
        *revtxtptr = *txtptr ;
        revtxtptr++;
    }
    *revtxtptr = ’\0’;
    printf (”The reverse text is : %s \n” , reverse) ;
    return 0; 
}
```

I want to see here output the reverse form of the input.
Something like
input:

```
CLEARLY
```

output:

```
YLRAELC
```

Could you help me to fix my fault?

Comment: You can't use "smart" quotes in C code. They have to be plain ASCII quotes.

Comment: `txtptr` needs to be initialized to the end of the input, not the beginning.

Comment: My code was in german, i have made many fault while i was translating it. Sorry for that.

Comment: You never initialized `N`. It need a value before you use it as the array sizes.

Comment: Turn off smart quotes when you're editing code.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Do you think that i have to delete this question? @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are corrections to your code:

1. You have spaces before the `.h>` in the `#include` lines.
2. You should limit the size of the buffers.
3. N is not initialized.
4. N is not being decremented.
5. `txtptr` is not being placed at the end of the C string, but it is being decremented in the `while` loop.
6. `scanf` is not limited to the size of the buffer(s) minus 1.
7. You need to either find the size of the string using `strlen` or walk the string until you find '\0'. (forward direction instead)
8. You use the wrong double-quotes and single quotes ("smart" quotes)

Here is a safe code that will reverse the input array (not in-place):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSTR 255
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

int main() {
  char text1[MAXSTR + 1];
  char revbuf[MAXSTR + 1];
  char* txtptr = text1;
  char* reverse = revbuf + MAXSTR;
  printf("\nEnter any text here : ");
  scanf("%" STR(MAXSTR) "s", text1);
  *reverse = '\0';
  while(*txtptr) {
    *--reverse = *txtptr++;
  }
  printf ("The reverse text is : %s \n" , reverse) ;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example function for int array.

```
int *reverseINTarray(int *array, size_t size)
{
    int *end, *wrk = array;
    if(array && size > 1)
    {
        end = array + size - 1;
        while(end > wrk)
        {
            int tmp = *wrk;
            *wrk++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

or

```
int *reverseINTarray(const int *src, int *dest, size_t size)
{
    int *wrk = dest;
    if(src && dest && size)
    {
        wrk += size - 1;
        while(size--)
        {
            *wrk-- = *src++;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: `strlen` or similar will be required to find the C string size.

Answer (score -2):

Your "swap two bytes" logic is ... simply ... *wrong.*  Does this give you any ideas?

```
char temp;
temp = *chartxtptr;
*chartxtptr = *txtptr;
*txtptr = temp;
```

You can't "swap" any two bytes without using a temporary to hold the byte that is about to be replaced.

Comment: He doesn't need to swap anything, the reverse is in a different array.